# 01/01/0001 when passing birth date to control

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I want to save a register form and must save birth date in another format.

In model I have:

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

In the view:

```
@model Univer.Model.KarApplicant
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "";
}
 <div class="container MainMiddle" style="padding-top:50px;">
<hr />
<div class="row container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <form asp-action="Register">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"> 
</div>

            <div class="form-row">
                ....
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <input asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control example1" data-val="false" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ....
            <div class="form-row">
               </div>
                <div class="form-group float-left">
                    <input type="submit" value="next" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


</div>
 @section Scripts {
  @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script src="~/lib/persian-date/persian-date.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/persian-datepicker/js/persian-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".example1").pDatepicker();
    });
</script>
}
```

When I click on Submit button and send data to action of controller, with breakpoint check *form value* that pass to controller, birth dates value that are passed to controller is `01/01/0001` but I have value in persian mode in input in view.

My question is: why when set value with javascript in input and send to controller the value doesn't get sent?

**UPDATE: after the comment i Added this code**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fa-IR");
        }); .....
   }
```

and

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {....
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseMvc()....
    }
```

Comment: What is the culture on the server? If it does not accept dates in that format, then it cannot be bound to your property by the ModelBinder. You would need to create your own custom ModelBinder, or post the date back in ISO (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format.

Comment: I update my code, the current culture in the server is ("en-US") and i need in my project ("fa-IR"), for this reason add new configuration to startup.cs